# IDA- Positive SP has been value found

Tags: ida

I'm trying to decompile an old binary of mine since I've lost it's source (formatted my computer). I'm facing the following issue when trying to decompile a function.

Why does it happen and how do I get past it step by step?

[image]

Comment: You should attach your binary file so that someone could have a look for you.